# One way road bridge with semaphore

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I am trying to implement a one way bridge using only semaphores/mutex, the one way bridge has three rules:

1. only cars from one direction can go at the a time.
2. There can be multiple cars going at the same direction as long as there is no cars coming at the opposite end.
3. If cars from the opposite direction arrive while there is cars on the bridge, the opposite cars wait till the bridge is cleared.
4. If more cars arrive at the bridge while cars of the same direction is already on the bridge, but there is already cars waiting on the opposite end, the newly arrived cars should also wait until bridge clears and all the opposite end cars also passes. It follows a first come first serve rule.

Here is a diagram fro Rule 4

(Alphabets represent cars, dashes represent the bridge)

```
B is alreaydy on the road:
    -----B-------
A arrives, waits for B:
    A---B--------
    A--B---------
now C arrives, same direction as B, and waits for B and A since A arrived first.
    A-B---------C
    AB----------C
B exits, A takes over
    -A----------C
    ...
    -----------AC
Finally A exits and C takes over
    -----------C-
```

Right now I have a mutex that locks the bridge when there are cars on it, but I cannot make Rule 4 happen. Any wiser ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When car approaches the bridge it is getting an incrementing token. When two cars are waiting on the opposite sides for the bridge to become free, the car with smaller token has a precedence. This should resolve your #4.

```
// initial conditions
bridge.calling = 1
bridge.next_ticket = 0

// car approaching the bridge
bridge.mutex.lock();
myself.ticket = ++ bridge.next_ticket
while (bridge.calling != myself.ticket)
    bridge.condition.wait(bridge.lock)
bridge.mutex.unlock()
// drive through the bridge
bridge.mutex.lock()
++ bridge.calling
bridge.mutex.unlock()
bridge.condition.notify_all()
```

Comment: how would I go about this? because I essentially have to use the queue builtin to the Semaphore object. I only have access to Wait() and Signal() methods of the semaphore/mutex

Comment: if you have a mutex you can have as much as you need of a thread safe state data. just have something like `bridge.get_next_token() { return ++internal_counter; }`

Comment: Right, thanks! but I already have something like that. I am stuck on  block both sides, or how do I make cars wait on both sides. I am thinking of using two mutex instead, one on each side but it's likely to run into deadlocks

Comment: you need one mutex and one conditional variable. do you have these available?